# Can I use bash vi bindings to enter vim while using other REPLs?

Tags: vim, terminal, ipython, read-eval-print-loop, pry

While using the vi bindings for bash, one can submit a multi-line command by typing 'v' in edit mode, and writing out the resulting temporary buffer. If VISUAL and EDITOR are set to `vim`, you can do this with vim. I've been raving about this feature, and I'd like to be able to do it in command-line REPLs such as ipython and pry. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a feature of the readline library (`<C-x><C-e>` does the same in the default mode) so you can probably work like in bash if your REPL uses readline. If your REPL doesn't use readline you will need to consult its documentation.

Speaking of documentation, you can find your answer in your REPL's documentation:

```
mysql:    \e
pry:      edit
ipython:  edit
```

RTFM before asking random strangers.

Comment: Sure, what I'm asking is whether there's a way to escape to a multi-line buffer while the terminal is being controlled by a process such as an interpreter. 

No need to swear at me, bud, I appreciate the answer :)